# What is the term for relation whose inversion is a function?

Tags: functions, reference-request, terminology, relations

> Do we have a conventional term/name for such a relation $R$ (which is not necessarily a function) that $R^{-1}$ is a function?

If not, what are your suggestions?

Comment: Is the given relation $R$ itself considered to be a function?

Comment: @coffeemath No, $R$ is not necessarily a function. Added in the post.

Comment: How do we define $R^{-1}$?

Comment: @DavidK $(x,y) \in R \iff (y,x) \in R^{-1}$. Is it standard?

Comment: That definition seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a relation in $A \times B$.

If you want $R^{-1}$ to be function on $B$, then you need $R$ to be injective and surjective.

Indeed, if $R$ is injective, then $R^{-1}$ is a function on the range of $R$.

If $R$ is surjective, then its range is $B$.

(A relation is *injective* iff $(a_1,b) \in R$ and $(a_2,b) \in R$ imply $a_1=a_2$.

A relation is *surjective* iff for every $b \in B$ there is $a \in A$ such that $(a,b) \in R$.)

Comment: Thanks. $R^{-1}$ is a function, however, it is not necessarily a function on the *domain* of $R$.

Comment: lfk -- Maybe you meant "If you want $R^{-1}$ to be a function on the *codomain* of $R$ etc".